# Analytic Proof of alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Having some problems figuring out the following proof. If we have a series $a_n$ that is both nonnegative and decreasing. Then if we consider the corresponding alternating series $$\sum (-1)^{n+1}a_n$$ I need to prove that the sequence of odd partial sums $$s_{2n+1}= \sum _{k=1}^{2n+1} (-1)^{k+1}a_k $$ is bounded and decreasing.

So if we start to write out some terms of this series we see the following,

$(-1)^2a_1+(-1)^3a_2+(-1)^5a_4+...+(-1)^{2n+2}a_k$

So the terms seem to always equal 1 but how do I show that this is bounded and decreasing?

Comment: Where are the $a_n$ in your sum on the second last line.

Comment: should they be on every term?

Comment: The series is of the form $(-1)^2(a_1) + (-1)^3(a_2)+.... $ .

Comment: Also this is not a linear algebra proof, it's an analytic proof.

Comment: okay thanks for your help, I have made a ciuple edits. Do you know how to proceed from here?

Comment: You should edit it so that you have $(-1)^3 a_2 + (-1)^5 a_4 + ... $

Comment: okay I have done that also

Comment: @hardmath thanks for the edit, would you be able to help me with my problem?

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: @hardmath thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$A_n
=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}a_k
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
A_{n+2}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+2} (-1)^{k+1}a_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1}a_k+(-1)^{n+2}a_{n+1}+(-1)^{n+3}a_{n+2}\\
&=A_n+(-1)^{n+2}(a_{n+1}-a_{n+2})\\
\end{array}
$

Putting $2n$
for $n$,

$\begin{array}\\
A_{2n+2}
&=A_{2n}+(-1)^{2n+2}(a_{2n+1}-a_{2n+2})\\
&=A_{2n}+(a_{2n+1}-a_{2n+2})\\
&>A_{2n}
\qquad\text{since }a_{2n+1}>a_{2n+2}\\
\end{array}
$

Putting $2n+1$
for $n$,

$\begin{array}\\
A_{2n+3}
&=A_{2n+1}+(-1)^{2n+3}(a_{2n+2}-a_{2n+3})\\
&=A_{2n+1}-(a_{2n+2}-a_{2n+3})\\
&<A_{2n+1}
\qquad\text{since }a_{2n+2}>a_{2n+3}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
the even terms are increasing
and
the odd terms are decreasing.

To show that
the odd terms are bounded below,

$\begin{array}\\
A_{2n+1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} (-1)^{k+1}a_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k+1}a_k+(-1)^{2n+2}a_{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} ((-1)^{2k}a_{2k-1}+(-1)^{2k+1}a_{2k})+a_{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{2k}(a_{2k-1}-a_{2k})+a_{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{2k-1}-a_{2k})+a_{2n+1}\\
&> 0\\
\end{array}
$

since all terms are positive.

To show that
the even terms are bounded above,

$\begin{array}\\
A_{2n+1}-A_{2n}
&=(-1)^{2n+2}a_{2n+1}\\
&=a_{2n+1}\\
&> 0\\
\end{array}
$

so
$A_{2n}
< A_{2n+1}
$.

Since the odd terms
are bounded below and decreasing,
the even terms are
bounded above.

Comment: thanks, this is a great explanation for why the sequence of odd partial sums is bounded and decreasing

Comment: Whenever I see an alternating series, my first step is to pair the even and odd terms together. This removes all the $(-1)^k$ and the result now depends only on the differences of the consecutive terms.

Comment: thanks for that tip I will keep that in mind for future problems